# Delete Account Error "Cascade deleting too many records"

Tags: account, cascadedelete

I would like to delete an account record. But It show to me error here: [image]

I also delete all related record with this account. When I check detail record. It don't have any Activity record.
[image]

What's happen here ? How can I delete it ?

Comment: I have retried many times. it have been deleted

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to delete the related records of the account record from the recyclebin as well when you get this error again which avoid referencing already deleted records.

Thank you!